# How to use Additional Module Dependencies in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I created a TestModule.ixx in one folder and I want to use `import TestModule` in my cpp project(in different folder).

I tried `TestModule=E:\XXX\TestModule.ixx.ifc;` in properties-> Additional Module Dependencies,  but got error lnk2019.

Q:
How to import module in other files? Is there a way like adding header file directory.

Module

```
export module TestModule;

#define ANSWER 42

namespace Example_NS
{
    int f_internal() {
        return ANSWER;
    }

    export int f() {
        return f_internal();
    }
}
```

Main:

```
import TestModule;
import std.core;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "The result of f() is " << Example_NS::f() << endl; // 42

    system("pause");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the build parameters we need to add it as an option.

When it comes to visual studio below is the way worked. Similarly there will a build option for other compilers.

In Visual studio (for MSVC) - Project properties--"C/C++"--Command Line--Additional options

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-reference?view=msvc-170

> /reference filename

```
/reference "C:\\Users\\Module.ixx.ifc"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried but still getting error lnk2019.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT: Did you link with the library that the other file built? Or if you didn't compile it into a library, the .obj file? The IFC file is like a header, so you still need to link against the actual product of compilation.